# Angular Select Option Values

Tags: angularjs, select

I am trying to populate my "Select" with the data in json.

Here's the code for that:

```
<select ng-model="showGroup" ng-options="c.DemographicId as c.Name for c in data.children" convert-to-number>
      <option value="">-- Choose Subevents --</option>
</select>
```

But don't know why the value in options shows like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's happend because angular auto-generate this (since angular 1.4.0 I think but I'm not 100% sure). You have to add a `track by` to avoid this.

```
<select ng-model="showGroup" ng-options="c.DemographicId as c.Name for c in data.children track by c.DemographicId" convert-to-number>
  <option value="">-- Choose Subevents --</option>
```

However, your `ng-model` will be fine anyway. There is no problem with this generated syntax.